# Duplicates across Multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need help in planning the best course of action to find duplicates from multiple tables.

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ID_T1 int, Col1 varchar(10), C2 varchar(10), C3 varchar(10), C4 varchar(10), Col5 varchar(10), Col6 varchar(10))
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (ID_T2 int, Col1 varchar(10), C2 varchar(10), C3 varchar(10), C4 varchar(10), Col5 varchar(10), Col6 varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @Table1 (ID_T1, Col1, C2, C3, C4, Col5, Col6)
SELECT 1, 'One', 'Test1', 'Line1', 'Record1', 'OTLR1', 'RLTO1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Two', 'Test2', 'Line2', 'Record2', 'OTLR2', 'RLTO2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Three', 'Test3', 'Line3', 'Record3', 'OTLR3', 'RLTO3'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Four', 'Test4', 'Line4', 'Record4', 'OTLR4', 'RLTO4'
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Five', 'Test5', 'Line5', 'Record5', 'OTLR5', 'RLTO5'
UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Six', 'Test6', 'Line6', 'Record6', 'OTLR6', 'RLTO6'
UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'Seven', 'Test6', 'Line6', 'Record6', 'OTLR7', 'RLTO7'
UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'Eight', 'Test8', 'Line8', 'Record8', 'OTLR8', 'RLTO8'

INSERT INTO @Table2 (ID_T2, Col1, C2, C3, C4, Col5, Col6)
SELECT 10, 'Ten', 'Test1', 'Line1', 'Record1', 'OTLR10', 'RLTO10'
UNION ALL
SELECT 20, 'Twenty', 'Test2', 'Line2', 'Record2', 'OTLR20', 'RLTO20'
UNION ALL
SELECT 30, 'Thirty', 'Test3', 'Line3', 'Record3', 'OTLR30', 'RLTO30'
UNION ALL
SELECT 40, 'Forty', 'Test4', 'Line4', 'Record4', 'OTLR40', 'RLTO40'
UNION ALL
SELECT 50, 'Fifty', 'Test5', 'Line5', 'Record5', 'OTLR50', 'RLTO50'
UNION ALL
SELECT 80, 'Eighty', 'Test80', 'Line80', 'Record80', 'OTLR80', 'RLTO80'
UNION ALL
SELECT 90, 'Ninety', 'Test90', 'Line90', 'Record90', 'OTLR90', 'RLTO90'

SELECT * FROM @Table1
SELECT * FROM @Table2
```

Now, C2, C3, and C4 can have either unique or duplicate values in Table1 and Table2.

I am trying to get three outputs.
Output 1 will have ONLY the records from Table 1 which has same C2, C3, and C4 columns' values in table 2 with Duplicate marked as 1/0 in Duplicate_SameTable

Output 2 will have ONLY the records from Table 1 which has same C2, C3, and C4 columns' values in table 2 with Duplicate marked as 1/0 in Duplicate_PrimaryTable

Output 3 will have the records from Table 1 and Tabl2 2 which has same C2, C3, and C4 columns' values with Duplicate marked as 1/0 in Duplicate_BothTables.

I can get the Output 1 from the following query.

```
SELECT *, CASE
            WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY  C2, C3, C4) > 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
         END AS Duplicate_SameTable
FROM @Table1
ORDER BY ID_T1 ASC
```

Output 2

```
SELECT B.ID, B.Col1, B.C2, B.C3, B.C4, B.Col5, B.Col6, CASE WHEN C.Duplicate_SameTable = 1 THEN 0 ELSE B.Duplicate_BothTables END AS Duplicate_PrimaryTable
FROM (
SELECT ID, Col1, C2, C3, C4, Col5, Col6, CASE
            WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY  C2, C3, C4) > 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
         END AS Duplicate_BothTables FROM ( 
SELECT ID_T1 AS ID, Col1, C2, C3, C4, Col5, Col6 FROM @Table1
UNION
SELECT ID_T2 AS ID, Col1, C2, C3, C4, Col5, Col6 FROM @Table2) A
) B INNER JOIN (SELECT *, CASE
            WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY  C2, C3, C4) > 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
         END AS Duplicate_SameTable
FROM @Table1) C ON B.ID = C.ID_T1
```

Output 3

```
SELECT B.ID, B.Col1, B.C2, B.C3, B.C4, B.Col5, B.Col6, CASE WHEN C.Duplicate_SameTable = 1 THEN 0 ELSE B.Duplicate_BothTables END AS Duplicate_PrimaryTable
FROM (
SELECT ID, Col1, C2, C3, C4, Col5, Col6, CASE
            WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY  C2, C3, C4) > 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
         END AS Duplicate_BothTables FROM ( 
SELECT ID_T1 AS ID, Col1, C2, C3, C4, Col5, Col6 FROM @Table1
UNION
SELECT ID_T2 AS ID, Col1, C2, C3, C4, Col5, Col6 FROM @Table2) A
) B LEFT JOIN (SELECT *, CASE
            WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY  C2, C3, C4) > 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
         END AS Duplicate_SameTable
FROM @Table1) C ON B.ID = C.ID_T1
ORDER BY B.ID
```

I am wondering how to go about getting Output 2 and Output 3.

One way I can think of doing is Union ALL Table 1 and Table 2 and then run above query. Or is there a better way of doing this as real tables will have millions of records and doing UNION ALL and then applying above query might take much longer.

Thank you

Edit: Updated this post with my try. Seems too messy and not sure if this is the best course of action performance wise.

Comment: Can you please **show** what **effort** you have put for Output 2 and Output 3.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just left join against the table your after. i.e.

```
SELECT t1.*, CASE WHEN t2.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as Duplicate 
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.c1=t2.c1 and t1.c2=t2.c2 and t1.c3=t2.c3
```